# node.js get data from array or object

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to access a data from a function, I thought it was an array so i made the `JSON.parse()` in order to split the array objects into var objects, but it seems to not be a real array, so I don't know what it is.

**This is the code:**

```
app.post('/', function(request, response)
{
    console.log('POST OK');
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost');

    var db = mongoose.connection;

    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
    db.once('open', function callback()
    {
        database.findByName(request.body.username.toLowerCase(), function(error, data)
        {
            if(error)
            {
                response.render('index',
                {
                    'Title': Title,
                    'result': 'Error, please try again later.'
                });
            }

            if(data.length > 0)
            {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                if(request.body.username == data.username && request.body.password == data.password)
                {
                    response.render('index',
                    {
                        'Title': Title,
                        'result': 'Log in success.'
                    });
                }

                else
                {
                    response.render('index',
                    {
                        'Title': Title,
                        'result': 'username/password invalid.'
                    }); 
                }
            }

            response.render('index',
            {
                'Title': Title,
                'result': 'Not found'
            });
        });
    }); 
});
```

One of the `if` statements is not working because `data.object()` is undefined so I made the log of the data and I get :

```
[{"username":"maggns","password":"22542214","other data"}]
```

The JSON.parse is not working, it throws me an error. Any idea how to parse this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like data is an array so you should be using:

```
if(request.body.username == data[0].username && request.body.password == data[0].password) {
  // response
}
```

Comment: isnt there another way to get this data without pointing index?

Comment: `data` is an array.  The reason it's returned as an array is because your `database.findByName` can return multiple objects that have the name `request.body.username.toLowerCase()`.  If you want only 1 object then you should use a function that returns an object instead of an array, like mongoose's findOne.

Comment: the api says that mongoose find() returns an array, while findOne()returns 1 thing, i thought that find would be the right for getting the whole record.

Comment: find returns an array of documents, findOne returns a single document.  A document is the 'whole record', an array is multiple records.

Answer (score 1):

It's malformed JSON, you can't parse it (short of a hacky route of using regexps or something). Assuming you're in control of the data, you should look to see how you're generating that string before placing it into mongodb.

Comment: the data is saved as array object. and that's how im retrieving it.

Comment: i just made a function that would make the mongoose connection and retrieve the data, the api says that object is an array. but its confusing why its not working

Comment: Then whatever api/process that is inserting the data is broken and needs to be fixed. You cannot have a single string like `"other data"` by itself in an object. You have to have both a key _and_ a value in a JavaScript object.